# Redirect a specific user id to a specific page on Login

Tags: php, mysql

There is a specific user in the database that I would like to redirect them to a specific page when they login:

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from login where password='$password' AND username='$username'", $connection);
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
//But not working
if ($rows == 1 && $id== 4) { 
    header("location: viewdemo.php"); // ID 4 Redirecting To this Page
} 
elseif($rows == 1) {
    header("location: view.php"); // Any other user To this Page
}   
else {
    $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}
// Closing Connection
mysql_close($connection);
}
```

I know the part I'm getting wrong is this:

```
if ($rows == 1 && $id== 4)
```

Comment: You're not using the database response.

Comment: Side notes: You should not use the `mysql_` set of functions anymore, you should not put user input into sql statements like that, and you should not store plaintext passwords. Look up PDO, bind parameters, and `password_hash()`.

Comment: `$rows` is a special result object returned by `mysql_query`. Can not be used that way. You need to use it in conjunction with `mysql_fetch_assoc( )` or `mysql_result( )`.

Comment: Thank you, i will look into password hashing after my functionality is working, For now can you please help me achieve what i want with the code posted

Comment: Thank you, i will look into password hashing after my functionality is working, For now can you please help me achieve what i want with the code posted

Comment: From where you are getting $id ?

Answer (score 1):

You will want to do do something that takes advantage of functions *(or classes, but that is probably beyond what you're able to do at this point)*:

**/config.php**

```
// Include this config file on every page, put your db credentials
define('DB_HOST','localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME','dbusername');
define('DB_PASSWORD','dbpassword');
define('DB_NAME','dbname');
define('DS',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('FUNCTIONS',__DIR__.DS.'functions');
// Start your session here.
session_start();
```

**/functions/connect.php**

```
// This is a very simplistic PDO connection, take a look at how to expand this
function connect()
    {
        return new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD);
    }
```

**/functions/query.php**

```
// This is a very basic query function, it will query safely if you do it right
// It will also return rows if you tell it to
function query($con,$sql,$return = false,$bind = false)
    {
        // The bind array is valuable to secure user input (from post or get)
        if(is_array($bind)) {
            foreach($bind as $key => $value) {
                $nkey           =   ":{$key}";
                $nBind[$nkey]   =   $value;
            }
        }
        // This then runs the safe query using the values
        if(!empty($nBind)) {
            $query  =   $con->prepare($sql);
            $query->execute($nBind);
        }
        // If you want to run a straight query, this will run instead
        else {
            $query  =   $con->query($sql);
        }
        // If you want to return data (from a select statement)
        // This will return an array of rows
        if($return) {
            while($result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $row[]  =   $result;
            }
            // Sends back any rows or 0 if no rows found
            return (!empty($row))? $row : 0;
        }
    }
```

**/functions/loginUser.php**

```
// This is a function to check login credentials. It's very flawed in that
// your passwording is very insecure
function loginUser($username,$password,$con)
    {
        $user   =   query($con,"select * from `login` where `password` = :0 AND `username` = :1",true,array($username,$password));

        return $user;
    }
```

**/login.php**

```
// Include all your required files
require_once(__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config.php');
require_once(FUNCTIONS.DS.'connect.php');
require_once(FUNCTIONS.DS.'query.php');
require_once(FUNCTIONS.DS.'loginUser.php');
// Get your database connection
$con    =   connect();
// Do the login
// I don't know where you get $username or $password from though....
$login  =   loginUser($username,$password,$con);
// Just see what is returned for your reference
print_r($login);
// If the login has returned a valid row
if($login != 0) {
    // Set the location by $id
    // I have no idea where you set $id...
    $location   =   ($id == 4)? "viewdemo.php" : "view.php";
    // Redirect
    header("location: ".$location);
    // It is good practice to exit here.
    exit;
}
else
    $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
```

Comment: This is better than the original example code, but it's worth mentioning that any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) usually has something like this built-in. For example [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) has a very robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) that works out of the box.

Comment: @tadman, true, it is definitely worth the OP's time to invest in a framework, especially if the OP wants to take this public. It would take much less work to use an established framework than to rebuild from scratch, especially when the original script is referencing things like `mysql_*`.

Comment: This answer is very helpful for anyone who's learning PHP, frameworks help a lot, but i'm not sure if they're useful for educational purposes.

Comment: @IzumiYanaro I agree, my answer is definitely a for-educational-purposes answer, I would not suggest anyone use this as the basis for a public website that had serious ambitions.

Comment: @IzumiYanaro The best way to learn is by example, but is very important to have good examples. The sorts of examples you get when searching for "PHP login system" are often the worst of the worst: Riddled with injection bugs, full of copy-paste code, using out-dated APIs and zero thought is given to security. A framework's code is rigorously audited by community, and usually follows some coherent design patterns. They are *much* better examples to work from. One you know what a login system must do, as in you've used several, then you're ready to implement one.